# WPF TreeView how to add TreeViewItem control template for child elements of TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, treeviewitem

how do I create treeview like this one:

```
 <TreeViewItem Header="Customers" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
```

- Customers

  - Anna

    - Delete
    - Open
  - Peter

    - Delete
    - Open
  - Andrew

    - Delete
    - Open

I would like to create child item template something like this

```
 <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Header}">
   <TreeViewItem Header="Delete"/>
   <TreeViewItem Header="Open"/>
 </TreeViewItem>
```

But it does not quite work that well because I end up having treeviewitem with datatemplate treeviewitem, but I would like to override controltemplate of child elements, but not parent.
Sure, I want to avoid my binding to be TreeViewItem, nor I want to create children with those static obejct "Open", "Delete".

Comment: Are Delete and Open just actions?

Comment: Yes, these are constant for all tree items, so I want to build them in XAML. That is why I want to use TreeViewItem as DataTemplate (which is obviosly wrong, yet you get my idea)

Comment: Do you really need to use TreeView or simply want similar arrangement of the items?

Comment: It is that existing desing uses TreeView. But in existing desing those nodes are constructed in code-behind. It is terible. I want to improve and move static sub-items to XAML and not populate TreeView with TreeViewItems in code behind and then use string comparing to identify which item was clicked! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) is one of the best articles about `TreeView` I ever read.

Inside `TreeView.Resources` you could declare several DataTemplates with different `DataType` if Delete and Open commands were items of some collection. (TargetType for the commands would be ICommand).

But it seems to mee you do not need TreeView at all.
Customers is a header of the list. If you want it to be epxpandable use [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) control.
Then it is sufficient to provide one data template for each customer.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="CustomerTypeName">
    <Expander Header="{Binding CustomerName}">
        <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCustomerCmd}" Content="Delete" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding OpenCustomerCmd}" Content="Open" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
    <Expander/>
<DataTemplate>
```

But here you'll have some troubles with selection highlight.

```
public class CommandWrapper
{
    ICommand Command {get;set;}
    string CommandName {get;set;}
}

public class CustomerViewModel
{
    Customer Customer {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<CommandWrapper> Commands {get;}
}
```

Let Customers be collection of `CustomerViewModel`.
Then the following XAML can help:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="TypeHoldingCustomersCollection" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
            <TextBlock Text="Customers"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="CustomerViewModel" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Customer.Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="CommandWrapper">
            <Button Content="{Binding CommandName}" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I need to put this in a TreeView, because Customers are in greater tree view of other nodes. :/

Comment: Ok, I get it. Do you still need commands (Delete and Open) to be tree nodes?

Comment: I guess so, so that they look same as in other places and have same design. It is not important if they are tree nodes, but if they were, they should look same as all tree (i guess)

Comment: Then you should create some wrapper for commands in your ViewModel.
I'll add some code.

Comment: Thnx, I got your point. So you are sugesting that I can not use TreeViewItem inside TreeView? What about using setters to achieve that?

Comment: TreeViewItem is generated automatically for each item. DataTemplate lets you adjust how data is presented inside TreeView. What do you mean by setters? adding items in code?

Comment: I could achieve my goal if I would be able to replace ControlTemplate of TreeViewItems bellow Customer. Maybe this can be achieved with Setters? I mean - what you suggest is very fine and I appreciate your help, but it sure wont look native neither have same styles. Moreover - what if I want underlying item "Actions" which can be open like treeviewitem.

Comment: May be ItemContainerStyle + ItemContainerSelector can help?